# creating category and subcategory dependent list box using asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying a create a page where I have a form to create the product. here I trying to creating category and subcategory dependent list box.but not understand how I will do that.
Here is my code:

```
public class Category
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

//my SubCategory model

 public class SubCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "SubCategory Name")]
        public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    }




//my product model

 public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Category Type")]

        public int CategoryTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryTypeId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "SubCategory Type")]

        public int SubCategoryTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SubCategoryTypeId")]
        public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Product Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_db.Category.ToList(), "Id", "CategoryName");           
            ViewData["SubCategoryId"] = new SelectList(_db.SubCategory.ToList(), "Id", "SubCategoryName");
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
                _db.Product.Add(product);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(product);
        }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model Amazon.Models.Product



@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<br />



<h2 class="text-info">Add New Product</h2>

<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="p-4 rounded border">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger">

        </div>

        <h3>@ViewBag.message</h3>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="CategoryTypeId"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <select asp-for="CategoryTypeId" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId" class="form-control"></select>
                @*<input asp-for="ProductTypeId" class="form-control" />*@
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="CategoryTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="SubCategoryTypeId"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <select asp-for="SubCategoryTypeId" asp-items="ViewBag.SubCategoryId" class="form-control"></select>
                @*<input asp-for="SpecialTagId" class="form-control" />*@
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="SubCategoryTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Back To List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{

    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");

    }
}
```

above code, I did successfully data-bind of my product controller and view.but I trying to creating category and subcategory dependent list box.but not understand how I will do that.
here my expectation output :

[image]

I am an absolute beginner. please help anyone.

Comment: `I trying to creating category and subcategory dependent list box` Would you like to implement cascading dropdownlist?

Comment: To create dependent or cascading dropdowns, you can dynamically populate SubCategory dropdown based on the previous selection of Category via JS code.

Comment: @FeiHan yes, I want to implement a cascading dropdown list. but i don't understand how I will do

Comment: Hi @ShaneWatson, you can refer to my post to implement a cascading dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I trying to creating category and subcategory dependent list box.

To implement cascading dropdown for `Category` and `Subcategory`, as I mentioned in comment, you can populate SubCategory dropdown based on the previous selection of Category in Category dropdown `change` event, like below.

You can try to modify your model class and implement one-to-many relationship between `Category` and `Subcategory` entities, so that you can store data like below in database and retrieve all sub-categories based on the provided CategoryId.

[image]

Populate only Category dropdown when page loads

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label asp-for="CategoryTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <select asp-for="CategoryTypeId" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
        </select>
    </div>
                
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label asp-for="SubCategoryTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <select asp-for="SubCategoryTypeId"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dynamically populate SubCategory dropdown in Category dropdown `change` event

```
$(function () {
    $("select#CategoryTypeId").change(function () {
        var cid = $(this).val();
        
        $("select#SubCategoryTypeId").empty();

        $.getJSON(`/Home/GetSubCategory?cid=${cid}`, function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("select#SubCategoryTypeId").append(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.name}</option>`);
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Action method `GetSubCategory`

```
public IActionResult GetSubCategory(int cid)
{
    var SubCategory_List=_db.SubCategory.Where(s => s.CategoryId == cid).Select(c => new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.SubCategoryName }).ToList();
    return Json(SubCategory_List);
}
```

Test Result

[image]

***Update:***

Model classes

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "SubCategory Name")]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```